# Как получить содержимое QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pandas, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Подскажите как вывести содержимое из `QListWidget`.
Пока при выборе директории выводится путь к файлам в `PlainText` и список в `ListWidget`, при выводе путь выводится как **`C:/`**, а содержимое как **`QListWidget at ...`**

```
def select_ws(self):
    self.dir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "choose directory")

    self.ws_dir.setPlainText(self.dir)
    if self.dir:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dir):
            for file_name in files:
                if file_name.endswith(".jpg):
                    self.WS_list.addItem(file_name)
def process(self):
        data = pd.DataFrame(dict(Путь=[self.dir],
                                 Список=[self.WS_list]))
        print(data)
```

вот что выходит:

```
Путь                                             Список
0  D:/МВК  <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QListWidget object at 0x00000...
```

а хотелось бы чтобы получался список файлов по этой директории.

Comment: Rishat Mukhtarov, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: S.Nick, добавил правки.

Comment: Привет, напиши в телегу @budda1123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QListWidgetItem *[**QListWidget::item(int row)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#item) const
>
> Возвращает элемент, занимающий данную строку в списке, если он был установлен; в противном случае возвращает nullptr.

> QString [**QListWidgetItem::text()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#text) const
>
> Возвращает текст элемента списка.

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textEdit) 
        vbox.addWidget(self.listWidget)        
        
        self.select_ws()
        self.process()
        
    def select_ws(self):
        self.dir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "choose directory")

        self.textEdit.setPlainText(self.dir)
        if self.dir:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dir):
                for file_name in files:
                    if file_name.endswith(".jpg"):
                        self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)

    def process(self): 
        list_item = [self.listWidget.item(row).text() for row in  range(self.listWidget.count())] # +++
        #print(*list_item, sep='\n')
        
        data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
            Путь=[self.dir], 
            Список=[list_item]))                                                                  # + list_item   
        print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]